# Using subquery to order results in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a simple Forum datastructure with ForumPost representing the Post and the answers. The class/table has a ParentId which is NULL for posts and which is set for answers. The class/table also has a createdAt field.
What I try to do is get all posts in the order of the last createdAt related to that post. So if answers are present the latest createdBy of the answers should be used for the order otherwise the createdAt of the post itself should be used.

This is quite easily done in SQL but I cannot find a way to do it in EF Core without EF not generating SQL but executing the orderby in code.

So a simple SQL version would be:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Content], [u].[CreatedAt], [u].[CreatedById], [u].[ForumId], [u].[ModifiedAt], [u].[ModifiedById], [u].[ParentId], [u].[Sticky], [u].[Title]
FROM [ForumPosts] AS [u]
WHERE ([u].[ForumId] = 1) AND [u].[ParentId] IS NULL
ORDER BY (
    SELECT MAX(tmp.CreatedAt) FROM ForumPosts AS tmp WHERE Id = u.Id OR ParentId = u.Id
) DESC;
```

So I tried to translate that into EF Code and came up with the following:

```
this.Context.ForumPosts
    .OrderByDescending(u => this.Context.ForumPosts.Where(a => a.Id == u.Id || a.ParentId == u.Id).Max(a => a.CreatedAt))
    .Where(u => u.ForumId == forumId && u.ParentId == null);
```

But this results in a warning that Max cannot be translated and will be executed in code.

I've tried several other version (e.g. using Select, OrderBy and Take(1)) but none worked.

I am using:

- Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.1

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You always can do this after retrieving query data, in memory. It could be even more effective from performance point of view, then in database query.

Comment: Max is an Immediate execution Method, thats why it gets executed and doesn't return a query. Read here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the answer myself. I'm not sure why I didn't try that one before, but it does the trick. The important thing seems to be not to use `First()` but to use `FirstOrDefault()`. It makes no sense in this szenario, because the query will always return at least one entry, but with `First()` EF will do the ordering in code and with `FirstOrDefault()` it will generate a relativly ok SQL query.

```
this.Context.ForumPosts
    .OrderByDescending(u => this.Context.ForumPosts.Where(a => a.Id == u.Id || a.ParentId == u.Id).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedAt).Select(a => a.CreatedAt).FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(u => u.ForumId == forumId && u.ParentId == null);
```